# Creating a custom categorized corpus in NLTK and Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I'm experiencing a bit of a problem which has to do with regular expressions and `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` in Python.

I want to create a custom categorized corpus and train a Naive-Bayes classifier on it. My issue is the following: I want to have two categories, "pos" and "neg". The positive files are all in one directory, `main_dir/pos/*.txt`, and the negative ones are in a separate directory, `main_dir/neg/*.txt`.

How can I use the `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` to load and label all the positive files in the pos directory, and do the same for the negative ones?

NB: The setup is absolutely the same as the `Movie_reviews` corpus (`~nltk_data\corpora\movie_reviews`).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275614/using-my-own-corpus-instead-of-movie-reviews-corpus-for-classification-in-nltk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question.
Since I was thinking about using two cases I think it's good to cover both in case someone needs the answer in the future.
If you have the same setup as the movie_review corpus - several folders labeled in the same way you would like your labels to be called and containing the training data you can use this.

```
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('~/MainFolder/', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')
```

The other approach that I was considering is putting everything in a single folder and naming the files 0_neg.txt, 0_pos.txt, 1_neg.txt etc. The code for your reader should look something like:

```
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('~/MainFolder/', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'\d+_(\w+)\.txt')
```

I hope that this would help someone in the future.