# How to save a custom categorized corpus in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How can one 'save' a new corpus to NLTK corpora data?

In my case, after I created a new custom categorized corpus in NLTK just like in this page said: [Creating a custom categorized corpus in NLTK and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463898/creating-a-custom-categorized-corpus-in-nltk-and-python)

I want to use it just like an already-installed corpora in NLTK (say movie_reviews). How can I do this? In other words, how can the new corpus I have read (say movie_reviews_0) can be called like this:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews_0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it to your own `nltk_data/corpora` folder which should be somewhere in your home directory. If you are on a Mac it would be in `~/nltk_data/corpora`, for instance. And it looks like you also have to append your new corpus to the `__init__.py` within `.../site-packages/nltk/corpus/`.