# loading files to categorized plain text corpus

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I am using ubuntu and as part of my assignment,im doing text sentiment analysis. I am making a training set to classify text using NaiveBayes classifier, i have many files containing sentences and saved as sent1.txt,sent2.txt. . .  and a file called label.txt

label.txt contains
sent1.txt:pos
sent2.txt:pos
...
sent 15:txt:neg
sent16.txt:neg

all the sent files and lable.txt files are stored in \home\abha.I tried this

```
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('.', r'.*\.txt', cat_file='cats/cats.txt')
```

Please tell me What should my third argument be?

Im having such silly issues with where to store the label.txt file and the sent files.

Comment: Hi! does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519171/583834

Comment: Yes,it worked for me.Thank you. i saved my files in the right folder n its working.