# Does nltk contain Arabic stop word, if not how can I add it?

Tags: nltk, arabic

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('arabic')
print(stopwords_list)
```

**Update [January 2018]:** The nltk data repository has included Arabic stopwords since October, 2017, so this issue no longer arises. The above code will work as expected.

Comment: The declaration of the source code encoding has nothing to do with the data you use (load/import), it is completely unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Yes I know, but i need this for another thing

Answer (score 7):

As of October, 2017, the nltk includes a collection of Arabic stopwords. If you ran `nltk.download()` after that date, this issue will not arise. If you have been a user of nltk for some time and you now lack the Arabic stopwords, use `nltk.download()` to update your stopwords corpus.

1. If you call `nltk.download()` without arguments, you'll find that the `stopwords` corpus is shown as "out of date" (in red). Download the current version that includes Arabic.
2. Alternately, you can simply update the stopwords corpus by running the following code **once,** from the interactive prompt:

   ```
   >>> import nltk
   >>> nltk.download("stopwords")
   ```

**Note:**

Looking words up in a list is really slow. Use a set, not a list. E.g.,

```
arb_stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("arabic"))
```

#### Original answer (still applicable to languages that are not included)

Why don't you just check what the `stopwords` collection contains:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> stopwords.fileids()
['danish', 'dutch', 'english', 'finnish', 'french', 'german', 'hungarian',
 'italian', 'norwegian', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'spanish', 'swedish',
 'turkish']
```

So no, there's no list for Arabic. I'm not sure what you mean by "add it", but the stopwords lists are just lists of words. They don't even do morphological analysis, or other things you might want in an inflecting language. So if you have (or can put together) a list of Arabic stopwords, just put them in a `set()`¹ and you're one step ahead of where you'd be if your code worked.

Comment: Sorry what you mean "put them in set()"..?

Comment: Make a list `my_stopwords_list`, then write `stopwords = set(my_stopwords_list)`. And look up `set()` in the Python docs.

Comment: Hi @alexis. `stopwords` now have an Arabic stop words, if you want to update your answer. Best Regrards.

Answer (score 5):

There's an Arabic stopword list here:

https://github.com/mohataher/arabic-stop-words/blob/master/list.txt

If you save this file in your nltk_data directory with the filename `arabic` you will then be able to call it with nltk using your code above, which was:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_list = stopwords.words('arabic')
```

(Note that the possible locations of your nltk_data directory can be seen by typing `nltk.data.path` in your Python interpreter).

You can also use alexis' suggestion to check if it is found.

Do heed his advice to convert the the stopwords list to a set: `stopwords_set = set(stopwords.words('arabic'))`, as it can make a real difference to performance.

Comment: IOError: No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\Lamiaa\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data\\corpora\\stopwords\\arabic' i get this error

Comment: One at a time, try putting it in every one of the directories listed when you type nltk.data.path

Comment: If that doesn't work, try putting this at the top of your file:

    `import nltk`

    `nltk.data.path.append(u'C:\Users\Lamiaa\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data\corpora\s‌​topwords')`

Comment: Nice that you found a stopwords list, but 1) Don't drop the file into the nltk corpus area, read it from your own folder with `nltk.corpus.WordListCorpusReader`. (Adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10519171/699305) answer). 2) Write your path as a "raw" string. You've got embedded newlines.

Comment: @alexis Could you explain why it's a bad idea not to put additional stopword files in the nltk corpus area? Are they in danger of being overwritten when nltk is updated?

Comment: Yes, among other things. The downloader will show you the stopwords corpus as "out of date" (or used to) because of the extra files. But mainly it's for the same reason that you shouldn't hack the nltk source itself to add new corpora: Keep your code in your project folders, and let libraries manage their own resources.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this library called Arabic stop words here is the pip for it:

```
pip install Arabic-Stopwords
```

just install it it should be imported after you type:

```
import arabicstopwords.arabicstopwords as stp
```

It is much better than the one in the `nltk`

Comment: You're correct. NTLK didn't even remove the word هذا.